# Rails Get the latest child record from model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Contract has_many Invoices. After creating a contract, the model automatically creates an invoice depending on certain form params.

I'm wanting to be able to select the most recently created invoice from a given contract.

This what I'm wanting to achieve:

```
contract = Contract.new(params)
contract.save

invoice = contract.invoices.most_recent  # < wanting to get the most recent

#or possible even do this if it's quicker
invoice = contract.most_recent_invoice
```

Which method is most proficient and what's the best way to go about doing this? Does Rails have a built in method? I just want to learn and maintain best practices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a class method to the Invoice model that orders them by created_at and returns the first one:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.most_recent
    order('created_at DESC').limit(1).first
  end
end

invoice = contract.invoices.most_recent # => Gives the last invoice created for this contract
```

Comment: This was what I was actually trying to do, however I was leaving off the `self.` on the method name since I wasn't going to be trying to access it directly by Class Name. Care to explain? If not, then at least it's working as I want it to now :) Thanks

Comment: This is one of the Rails' faults in my opinion. Defining collection methods as class methods is really confusing, especially since scopes do the exact same thing, but with different syntax. Any method that you declare as a class method gets gets "applied" to relations as well, which is why this works. I wrote sort of a proof of concept gem a few months ago called [Herd](https://github.com/beerlington/herd) that allows you to define collection methods in a separate class. I'm not recommending you use it for production, but it's there if you are interested in exploring the source.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [last](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last) method. Example:

```
contract = Contract.new(params)
contract.save

invoice = contract.invoices.last
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this, but I don't think it guarantees that it's the last invoices which was create (maybe depends on the database?).

Comment: You can specify an `:order` parameter to the `has_many` relation, that ensures the sorting of the items.

Comment: @Baldrick, since rails automatically adds timestamp fields I thought that last method was implemented in regard to created_at column, as you implemented in your answer. I am not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

Create scope for `most_recent_invoice` order by created_at and create `limit` scope which will limit the no of records(for best practise)